# Groovy - Trait in a Constain in Generic

Tags: generics, groovy, traits, generic-constraints

I have a problem with using a Trait as "extends" Constrain in Groovy.
Problem can be summarised as this:

Following works:

```
interface AInterface {
    String getA()
}
trait ATrait implements AInterface {
    String a
}
class AClass implements ATrait {}
class GenericClass<T extends AInterface> {}
GenericClass<AClass> instance
```

And following doesn't:

```
interface AInterface {
    String getA()
}
trait ATrait implements AInterface {
    String a
}
class AClass implements ATrait {}
class GenericClass<T extends ATrait> {} // XXX: instead of AInterface
GenericClass<AClass> instance
```

It doesn't make any sense to me maybe a bug in Groovy? I tried both groovyc and groovy in 2.5.8 and 3.0.0 (rc) versions.

Thank you for any help, traits are very useful to me and I would rather not introduce dummy interfaces to serve as generic constaint - even if this is some workaround.